# Public vs Private inner classes in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes, access-specifier

I was reading introduction to Java programming and it does not have a good explanation regarding this topic and it made me wonder why should someone use a private inner class in java instead of using a public one.

They both can be used only by the outer class.

Comment: think it as a member of the class. why do you set a member private?

Comment: The same reason you would use a public vs private member.

Comment: [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial.

Comment: @StinePike to negate acess to another class.@arshajii I thought it had something more.

Comment: OO design principle: minimize visibility.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your claim `They both can be used only by the outer class.` is wrong:

```
public class A {
    private class B {}
    public class C {}
    public C getC() { 
        return new C();
    }
    public B getB() {
        return new B();
    }

}
public class Tryout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A.B b = a.getB(); //cannot compile
        A.C c = a.getC(); //compiles perfectly
    }
}
```

Note that you can actually have an instance of `A.C` in another class and refer to it as `C` (including all its public declaration), but not for `A.B`.

---

From this you can understand, you should use private/public modifier for inner classes the same way you use it generally.